# What's the youngest that a shochet could be?

Tags: halacha, age, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Is there a lower age limit to be able to shecht (slaughter animals in a kosher manner)? If so, what is it?

> Related question: [Is age a disqualification for Shechita?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8567/5323) (upper age limit)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [*lechatchila*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323) age minimum, according to [Simlah Chadasha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37555/5323) ([1:30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=16)), is **18 years old**, because at that point a person is a "בר דעת" and knows how to be careful with things. This minimum can be bypassed if a person is an exceptional ירא שמים, and is considered to be a גדול (adult; see footnote for technical definition).

What would happen if a minor* slaughtered?

1. **A child that has not mastered fine motor skills:** This child's שחיטה is **not kosher,** even if he knows all of הלכות שחיטה *and* and older person who was observing saw that he did not make a mistake in the slaughter.
2. **A child that has mastered fine motor skills:** This child's שחיטה is **kosher [*b'dieved*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323)**, but only if an older person observed from beginning to end. This category is different from the first in that he is considered to be a "בר זביחה," someone who is able to slaughter; however, this is still not *lechatchila*, because he could still make a mistake and the observer may not notice.
3. **A child that knows הל' שחיטה *and* has fine motor skills:** This child **may slaughter *lechatchila*, under supervision.** If he was not supervised, then the meat is אסור (forbidden), because most actions of children are not done properly, and because he is a קטן (minor), then we can not trust his testimony (עד אחד נאמן באיסורים).

---

*"Minor" (קטן) for these purposes is defined as younger than 13 years and one day for boys; [for women](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8538/5323), younger than 12 and a day.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify @Shokhet's answer - there is no lower age limit, as long as the child can slaughter and he is being supervised. This is found in Shulchan Aruch 1:5. The Rema there comments that there are those who are machmir not to give a kabala for shchita to someone under 18, just like the Simlah Chadasha says.

The Shulchan Aruch's language is "יודע לאמן ידיו לשחוט" which is more accurately translated as - the child's hands have mastered the skill to shecht, and not the more general - "mastered fine motor skills" as @Shokhet translated.